# Can't resize Folder properties window

Tags: windows-server-2003, directory, groups

I've opened the properties window of a folder to view it's security groups, but the security group names are too long to be fully readable in the security tab.

There is no way to resize the window.

Is there a logical purpose for this, or is it just designed to be a complete pain in the ass.

Happens on Win Server 2003, and Windows 7.

Comment: Please don't [cross-post](http://superuser.com/questions/240285/cant-resize-folder-properties-window).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try clicking the `Advanced` button then double click the dividing line between the `Name` and `Permission` fields in the column headers. You'll know your mouse pointer is in the correct position to do this when the cursor changes to a vertical bar with left and right arrows. This should expand the width of the column so that it's equal to the longest entry and provide a horizontal scrollbar.

Comment: Bravo.  You would think it simple to add this to the default window.

Comment: Mmm, reminds me of the 'advanced' option to get to the more useful user account settings (like the 'security' tab...)